# The log file is just for log or it is to stored the message?

Tags: java, apache-pulsar, pulsar

For the pulsar bookeeper, the log file under the path `/bookkeeper/ledgers/current/*.log` is just the log file or it is used to store the message?

Will it will lose the message, if I delete the log file?

Answer (score 0):

It's where messages entry data are stored. Don't delete that :-) !